# SmartGWT: ComboBox - ValueMap not appearing

Tags: java, combobox, smartgwt

I'm still newbie in SmartGWT, currently having a strange problem..

I am using Windows XP and SmartGWT version 3.0,
GWT SDK 2.4.0 (using Eclipse IDE).

So my problem is, I kind of copied examples from the SmartGWT showcase: [Styled ComboBox](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category)

```
DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
ComboBoxItem cb = new ComboBoxItem();
cb.setValueMap("cat", "dog", "bird");
cb.setTitle("Select:");
df.setItems(cb);
...
layout.addMember(df);
```

And when I run it as Web Application, the valuemap doesn't appear.
I mean, the [v] button is there but nothing happens when i clicked it..

Sorry for the noob question, and thanks for your help! :D

---

UPDATE - 05/03/2012

Here is what appears on my browser:

screenshot removed

Here is the full standalone code:

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.example.helloworld.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.DynamicForm;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.ComboBoxItem;


    public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {

        public void onModuleLoad() {

            VLayout layout = new VLayout();
            layout.setWidth100();
            layout.setHeight100();

            DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
            ComboBoxItem cb = new ComboBoxItem();
            cb.setTitle("Select :");
            cb.setValueMap("Cat", "Dog", "Bird");

            df.setItems(cb);
            layout.addMember(df);

            layout.draw();
        }
    }
```

**HelloWorld.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='helloworld'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->

  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" />

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.example.helloworld.client.HelloWorld'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

On the 'Development Mode' tab in Eclipse (the one that shows you link to run on browser),
i get this message:

> [INFO] [helloworld] - Your *.gwt.xml module configuration prohibits
>   the use of the current doucment rendering mode (document.compatMode='
>   CSS1Compat').
> Modify your application's host HTML page doctype, or
>   update your custom 'document.compatMode' configuration property
>   settings.

There is also a single warning:

> The following classpath entry 'C:\some-path\smartgwt-3.0\smartgwt.jar'
>   will not be available on the server's classpath.

---

UPDATE 2 - HTML and CSS file

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HelloWorld.css">

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helloworld/helloworld.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS file:

```
/** Add css rules here for your application. */


/** Example rules used by the template application (remove for your app) */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777777;
  margin: 40px 0px 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sendButton {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

/** Most GWT widgets already have a style name defined */
.gwt-DialogBox {
  width: 400px;
}

.dialogVPanel {
  margin: 5px;
}

.serverResponseLabelError {
  color: red;
}

/** Set ids using widget.getElement().setId("idOfElement") */
#closeButton {
  margin: 15px 6px 6px;
}
```

---

IMPORTANT UPDATE

I forgot to inform you that I am currently using Google Chrome(18.0.1025.168) for debug / test build. When I ran it on Firefox, it runs OK!

I noticed this [thread](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aChrome) a bit late.. So this is currently a known bug.

**conclusion: do NOT use google chrome for GWT / smartGWT development mode (for now).**

Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: Can you post a standlaone case so that I can can also reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually, the problem above is the actual standalone case D: I got confused as of why the combo box is not showing their valuemaps, so I created a new project just to make a single combobox. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: standalone code should run successfully without any changes. Will this code run if I directly put it in OnModuleLoad()? And if this is the only code, then I can't find any issue in this.

Comment: Yep, I am running it directly in onModuleLoad. Very confusing @@... Maybe I'll post my full code, its xml, and warning messages also screenshots later when I get back home to provide better information.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide full relevant standalone code and the error details.

Comment: Updated! :) Maybe i should redownload the SmartGWT? :x

Comment: What happens when you click on combo ? Is it empty ?

Comment: Please post your HTML file. Are you using external CSS ?

Comment: No, i have never touched the .html and the .css file :) Will update it right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to inform you that I am currently using Google Chrome(18.0.1025.168) for debug / test build. When I ran it on Firefox, it runs OK!

I noticed this [thread (smartclient forum)](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aChrome) a bit late.. So this is currently a known bug.

**conclusion: do NOT use google chrome for GWT / smartGWT development mode (for now).**

Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    Map<String,String> valuesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    valuesMap.put("cat","cat");
    valuesMap.put("dog","dog");
    valuesMap.put("bird","bird");
    cb.setValueMap(valuesMap);
    cb.setTitle("Select:");
    df.setItems(cb);
    ...
    layout.addMember(df);
```

Comment: I tried it (with a LinkedHashMap tho) and it still won't appear. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

```
DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.setValueMap("cat", "dog", "bird");
cb.setTitle("Select:");
//other fields
df.setFields(cb); // Use this to add fields
layout.addMember(df);
```

Have a look At [Show Case](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_various)

Comment: I've changed the method to setFields, but it still won't appear.. :D

Comment: Look At Show Case example given in the link

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox is not SmartGWT. Where is it coming from ?

This code works as expected :

```
DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
ComboBoxItem cb = new ComboBoxItem();
cb.setValueMap("cat", "dog", "bird");
cb.setTitle("Select");
df.setItems(cb);

HLayout layout = new HLayout();
layout.addMember(df);
layout.draw();
```

Comment: Ah, sorry! I meant ComboBoxItem. Thanks for pointing it out :) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debug mode you never will see the content of this selectItem or comboBox, but if you select down with the keyboard you will see the content. You should be in "production" mode for see everything correctly

Is a problem with chrome, if you work with firefox you will see the content